# Power BI - How multiple developers can work on a same report?

Tags: powerbi

Power BI - How multiple developers can work on a same report?
If scenario comes in which you need 3 developers to work on data-model side and creating DAX Measures and you also need 3 developers to make visualizations, then how they can co-ordinate their work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How multiple developers can work on a same report?

Short answers is you can't, Power BI is not set up to be used in this manner.

You will have to separate out the report design into the backend (data model) and the frontend (the report), so you deploy the data model, then connect to that data model to build the frontend, but you will not be able to work on the same report at once, either in the desktop or the service.

You can have people working on the backend, using Sql Server Development Tools (SSDT) to create the data model, then use the Power BI XMLA endpoint to deploy to it. But you'll have to check in/out the data model, and merge in devops/github. Which isn't great and you'll run into issues if your XMLA isn't correct, or you overwrite peoples changes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Break apart the data model from the report. Save two pbix files. One for the dataset and one for the report.
2. save files on teams/sharepoint so that you have version history.
3. For the developers working simultenously on the report, I suggest all report changes be done in the service.
4. For devs working on the dataset/dax, they need to communicate when they are about to make changes so they don't save over others' work.